# Assembling a QTextDocument from fragments

Tags: qt, qtextdocument, qtextcursor

I want to put together a `QTextDocument` from multiple `QTextDocumentFragment`s, separated by horizontal rules represented by `<HR>`.  Something like this (as an ASCII mock-up):

```
foo
-------
bar
-------
baz
```

My attempt to do this (using `insertText()` instead of `insertFragment()` for now, to try to get the basic scheme working, but the same thing happens with `insertFragment()`) looks like this:

```
QTextEdit *textedit = ui->descriptionTextEdit;
QTextDocument *textdoc = textedit->document();

textedit->clear();

QTextCursor insertion(textdoc);
insertion.movePosition(QTextCursor::Start, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor);

insertion.insertText("foo");
insertion.insertBlock();
insertion.insertHtml("<HR>");
insertion.insertBlock();
insertion.insertText("bar");
insertion.insertBlock();
insertion.insertHtml("<HR>");
insertion.insertBlock();
insertion.insertText("baz");

qDebug() << textdoc->toHtml();
```

The results from this are truly bizarre.  Here's a screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, I requested two `<HR>` tags but I got five horizontal rules!  The HTML for the QTextDocument is bizarre too (I've added a couple of newlines to make it more readable):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">
<html>
<head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" />
<style type=\"text/css\">
p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }
</style></head>
<body style=\" font-family:'.SF NS Text'; font-size:13pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">
<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">foo</p>
<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">bar</p>
<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">baz</p>
</body></html>
```

There is no sign of my `<HR>` tags in the HTML at all.  With slightly different strategies – called `insertBlock()` only before the `<HR>` insertions, or only after them, or not at all – I get variations on this theme; sometimes `bar` and `baz` are not visible in the HTML output, but the abundance of `<HR>` tags are, instead.  For example, if I change the insertion code to this:

```
insertion.insertText("foo");
//insertion.insertBlock();
insertion.insertHtml("<HR>");
insertion.insertBlock();
insertion.insertText("bar");
//insertion.insertBlock();
insertion.insertHtml("<HR>");
insertion.insertBlock();
insertion.insertText("baz");
```

then I get a result that has four horizontal rules in the visible rendering in my app, and has this HTML output:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">
<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" />
<style type=\"text/css\">
p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }
</style></head>
<body style=\" font-family:'.SF NS Text'; font-size:13pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">
<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">foo</p>
<hr />
<hr />
<hr />
<hr />
</body></html>
```

Note that `bar` and `baz` are not visible in the HTML output, although they do render visibly in the app.

But in no permutation of the code that I have found do I get what I want.  It looks like I am putting `QTextDocument` into some kind of internally inconsistent or confused state.  So: what's the right way to do this?

This is with Qt 5.9.8 on macOS 10.14.6.

Comment: Pretty strange... confirmed on Qt 5.12.4 (Win7). It definitely doesn't like `hr`s (removing them seems to make it all act normal). But the "screenshot" output (of the "live" document being manipulated) is a bit of a red herring... if you start with a new blank `QTextDocument` and do the same insertion steps, then `QTextEdit::setHtml(textdoc.toHtml())`, it at least looks like the produced HTML code. When manipulating the QTextEdit's own document, then it looks unlike the produced HTML (as in your screenshot).

Comment: Presumably the `setHtml(toHtml())` wipes away the inconsistent internal state.  But that still doesn't get me where I want to be.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround that seems acceptable, although it is not optimal.  In between each text fragment, I now do this:

```
insertion.insertBlock(hrBlockFormat);
insertion.insertText("––––––––––––––––––––");
insertion.insertBlock(defaultBlockFormat);
```

That string is a series of en-dashes (option-hyphen, on macOS).  They display cleanly as a solid line in the `QTextEdit`, with no breaks between the characters, at least in the font I happen to be using, on macOS, etc.  I don't know how portable this solution is, so a better solution will be accepted.  The horizontal rule's width does not fill the view, though; it is just dictated by the number of dashes you use, which sucks.  Also, this solution of course produces a series of dashes in the HTML, rather than an `<HR>`; I happen not to care about that, but it's also non-optimal in general.

The block formats are set up as follows:

```
QTextBlockFormat defaultBlockFormat;
QTextBlockFormat hrBlockFormat;
hrBlockFormat.setTopMargin(10.0);
hrBlockFormat.setBottomMargin(10.0);
hrBlockFormat.setAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter);
```

That makes the horizontal rule centered, and provides some vertical space around it.